# Como redirecionar subdomínio para IP fixo em porta específica

Tags: dns, subdomínio

Estou utilizando um aplicação web que roda na porta 8180 e gostaria de redirecionar meu subdomínio para o IP do meu servidor na porta 8180. 
Nas zonas de DNS, criei uma entrada do tipo A, mas só consigo informar o IP, e porta não tá dando certo.

Como fazer esse redirecionamento, ou seja, quando digitar `service.meusite.com.br` ele irá redirecionar para o meu servidor na porta `8180` ficando algo como `123.45.678.90:8180`?

Answer (score 5):

Isto que você quer fazer, **não é possível fazer unicamente com DNS**. DNS resolve apenas endereços, não portas. Para redirecionar HTTP para outra porta, é preciso um servidor HTTP. Temos então duas alternativas.

Se o endereço do subdomínio (123.45.678.90) estiver com a porta 80 livre (o que não acredito seja o caso, senão você não ia querer usar a porta 8180), você deve colocar um servidor Web atendendo na porta 80 e redirecionando qualquer requisição para http://subdominio.meusite.com.br:8180.

Se o endereço do subdomínio (123.45.678.90) já estiver usando a porta 80 para o domínio principal (acredito que seja seu caso), você deve habilitar o uso de Virtual Host no servidor da porta 80, porque aí um único servidor Web pode atender diversos domínios num mesmo endereço. Num virtual host você coloca o domínio, no outro virtual host o subdomínio que redireciona tudo para :8180.

A configuração de virtual host varia de acordo com o servidor web que você está usando, então não vou entrar em detalhes.